# What bean species are best for baked beans?

Tags: beans, crockpot

I want to cook baked beans, the slowcooker version. I want to make it from dry beans. My question is: what sort of beans will be best for this dish? I need at least 2-3 alternatives, cause I live in Poland, and I'm not sure if I will be able to buy some more exotic species...

Comment: There's a place near me that uses butter beans.  The larger bean has a much different surface to mass ratio, which results in less sauce needed for the same mass of beans.

Comment: @Joe: Isn't the sauce (aka "where the calories hide") the best part? ;-)

Comment: Butter beans also hold shape better with long cooking so make an ideal baked bean imho. love Limas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you live in Poland, you should easily find the "normal" white ones in your supermarket. They should be good for baked beans, although the British version uses white beans that are a bit smaller.

For more American style beans, you could also use the pinkish-brown or spotted type.

There are so many types of beans, that I can't give a specific "name". Stick with the smaller ones, as they have less starchy parts and usually keep their shape better.

Comment: Great thanks! Will try that! :) I have access to the smaller ones and to the spotted ones for sure.

Comment: American style baked beans usually use navy beans. [Here is an example from Food.com](http://www.food.com/recipe/all-american-baked-beans-326290)

Comment: Good advice, however, you won't find "navy beans" under this name here in Europe. That's why I tried to *describe* them as far as I could.